# Unexpected token with msbuild script?

Tags: msbuild

I get the following error message when trying to run a build file:

error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. '?' is an u
nexpected token. The expected token is ''>''.

Here is the build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?/>

<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTarget="Compile"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == " ">Debug</Configuration>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<SolutionRoot Include=".."/>
<BuildArtifacts Include=".\buildartifacts\"/>
<SolutionFile Include="..\ScrewTurnWiki.sln"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Clean">
<RemoveDir Directories="@(BuildArtifacts)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Init" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
<MakeDir Directories="@(BuildArtifacts)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Init">
<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)"Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifacts.FullPath);   
    Configuration=$(Configuration)"/>
</Target>

</Project>
```

Line 1, Position 38 is where it says the error is.

Another error just popped up after fixing the first one:

Line 1, Postion 53 says Name cannot begin with the '"' character....

Comment: Ironically, just looking at the syntax highlighting for XML in the question is enough to spot the problem. Use editor with syntax highlighting to edit XML! (VS one is pretty decent)

Comment: the / was the problem, but now I have another problem.  I got this from an msdn article and copied it verbatim.  The link is in the comment I put under coelhudo's response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the xml header must be 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` instead of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?/>`

Comment: That fixed that issue, but now I get another error on line 7, postion 53.  It says, Name cannot begin with the '"' character, hexidecimal value 0x22.  I got this script from this msdn article, so apparently some mistakes were made:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd758790.aspx

Comment: There is 3 " characters, you are missing one, I think it's:
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == " " ">Debug</Configuration>

Comment: Thanks, I did that, I just had to put '' instead of "".  Thanks for help.

Comment: You should use Visual Studio to edit those files. If it is a project itself then right-click on the project and then pick unload, and then right-click again and pick edit. If it is not an actual VS project then just open the file itself.