# Msbuild is not compiling the project?

Tags: msbuild

This is in reference to this question:

[Unexpected token with msbuild script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522478/unexpected-token-with-msbuild-script)

I fixed the errors, but when I run msbuild ScrewTurnWiki.build, it does not compile the solution.  The buildartifacts directory is not created either.

Let me rephrase, when I build it, it says Build Succeeded and 0 errors, 0 warnings, but it does not create the buildartifacts output directory.

Ok, if I run it like this:

msbuild ScrewTurnWiki.build /t:Compile

It creates the directory with a couple files, but gives me the error message:

C:\ScrewTurnWiki\WebDeployment\WebDeployment.wdproj(42,11): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" was not
 found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
the file exists on disk.

LOG FILE

Build started 10/6/2009 8:54:23 AM.
Project "C:\ScrewTurnWiki\Build\ScrewTurnWiki.build" on node 0 (default targets).
Building with tools version "3.5".
Target "Clean" in file "C:\ScrewTurnWiki\Build\ScrewTurnWiki.build" from project "C:\ScrewTurnWiki\Build\ScrewTurnWiki.build":
Using "RemoveDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "RemoveDir"
  Directory ".\buildartifacts\" doesn't exist. Skipping.
Done executing task "RemoveDir".
Done building target "Clean" in project "ScrewTurnWiki.build".
Done Building Project "C:\ScrewTurnWiki\Build\ScrewTurnWiki.build" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `msbuild ScrewTurnWiki.build /fl` and then look at the generated file (msbuild.log) for more info and paste it here?

Comment: Ok, I will updated my post.  I just saw your name and realized that your are the one that James Kovaks thanks for helping him troubleshoot his build in that article I mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Is the value for DefaultTargets on the Project element set to Clean? If yes can you change that to the correct value? If there is none then you should either specify the DefaultTargets value on the Project node or use the /t:TARGET_TO_EXECUTE from the command line. It looks to me like you have no default specificed and the Clean target is the first one so it just executes that.

Comment: Actually, I had the default targets set, but I had it as DefaultTarget, not DefaultTargets (notice the missing s).  After I added that, it worked, but now I have some other errors relating to the actual project, but I will not get into that here.  Thanks for the help on the first one.